# Is it possible to save a video to the videos application rather than the photos application?

Tags: ios

The method writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum: seems a bit daft to me, both as a developer and as a user.

If an application offers the user the ability to save a video, then the only option available for the developer to use to implement that functionality is ALAssetsLibrary:writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum AFAIK.

But then when the user goes to look for it, naturally they will assume its in the Videos app on their desktop, but its not, instead it has to be accessed by the Photos app.

This is totally unintuitive for the user.

Is there anyway an app can save a video so the user can find it when they launch the video app?

Answer (score 0):

No. It's sandboxed out. I disagree with your assumption of a users inclination to check the videos app. When they record a video on an iOS device, it doesn't go to the videos app. Everybody is used to going to their photos app for stuff like that. Also, it's the way the phone has always worked, so it's the most intuitive place to put it.